# Мелочовка или мелочёвка

Tags: орфография

Почему в словарях встречаются оба варианта, но без комментариев? Есть ведь правило правописания о-ё в суффиксах и окончаниях существительных после шипящих?!

Answer (score 5):

Правильно: мелочовка, речовка, плащовка. Буква *О* пишется в суффиксе имен существительных -*овк*- (в отыменных производных словах), например: чиж — чижовка (самка чижа), мелочь – мелочовка, речевой — речовка, плащевой — плащовка, грушевый — грушовка; а также в суффиксе имен прилагательных -*ов*-, например: ежовый, парчовый, холщовый. Буква *О* пишется также в слове *крыжовник*, где суффикс в современном языке не выделяется. Буква *Ё* пишется в отглагольных сушествительных на -*ёвка*, например: ночевать – ночёвка, корчевать – корчёвка.

**Раньше** правильным было написание *мелочёвка, плащёвка*: эти слова считались исключениями. Сейчас их написание подведено под общее правило и зафиксировано в «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН под ред. В. В. Лопатина.

Мелочовка (прежняя мелочёвка) — не отглагольное сушествительное.

Answer (score -1):

В суффиксах посше шипящих под ударением всегда пишется О.
Примеры: *собачОнка, девчОнка, мелочОвка, родничОк*.

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, правильный ответ, одобренный другими участниками.

Comment: @grizzly  Уважаемый автор с 11-го года сайт не посещает.