# Как правильно: плащёвка/плащовка, мелочёвка/мелочовка, речёвка/речовка?

Tags: орфография

**Из словаря на ГРАМОТЕ.РУ**

**МЕЛОЧЁВКА**, Разг. 1. Мелкие предметы; мелочь. Галантерейная м. Купить мелочёвку. 2. Второстепенные детали, обстоятельства какого-л. дела. Проект закончен? - Почти, м. осталась.

**ПЛАЩЁВКА**,  Разг. Плащевая ткань. Синяя п. Юбка из плащёвки.

**Из правил Лопатина НА ГРАМОТЕ.РУ:** Отыменные существительные на –овка типа **мелочовка, ножовка, плащовка** следует отличать от отглагольных существительных типа ночёвка.

А трещать - трещотка и распахнуть - распашонка, это отглагольные существительные?

Answer (score 2):

Отглагольные существительные корреспондируют с глаголом: ночёвка - ночевать, корчёвка - корчевать, межёвка - межевать, растушёвка - растушевать.

Еще век назад в корректорских недоумевали: ну почему "мелочёвка", нету же глагола "мелочевать"?!

Ну вот, словари исправились. Теперь у нас **плащовка, мелочовка, речовка.**

Ответ Грамоты.ру:

> Правила таковы. Буква О пишется в суффиксе имен существительных -овк-
>   (в отыменных производных словах) , например: чиж – чижовка (самка
>   чижа) , мелочь – мелочовка, речевой – речовка, плащевой – плащовка,
>   грушевый – грушовка; а также в суффиксе имен прилагательных -ов-,
>   например: ежовый, парчовый, холщовый. Буква О пишется также в слове
>   крыжовник, где суффикс в современном языке не выделяется. Буква Ё
>   пишется в отглагольных сушествительных на -ёвка, например: ночевать –
>   ночёвка, корчевать – корчёвка.    Отметим, что раньше правильным было
>   написание мелочёвка, плащёвка: эти слова считались исключениями.
>   Сейчас их написание подведено под общее правило и зафиксировано в
>   «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН под ред. В. В. Лопатина.

Более развернуто правило представлено на сайте [**Культура письменной речи**](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.10).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Трещотка тоже отглагольное. Рекомендуют запомнить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Распашонка -  ***о*** после шипящих под ударением. Отглагольное.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо раз за разом вставлять картинки того, что можно написать словами. От них ресурсу - никакой пользы, только траффик грузят. Да и по сути ответ отвратительный, Многословие из ничего.  Человек просто спутал суффиксы, зачем столько информации по разным поводам на него выплёскивать?!

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно по вопросу.

> трещать - трещотка и распахнуть - распашонка, это отглагольные
>   существительные?

Первое, трещотка - нет. Оно напрямую от слова треск (или гипотетического трещ**о**т), глагольного суффикса там нет. 
Второе - да, отглагольное.

Теперь по сути. Правилами (у Лопатина и вообще) устанавливается написание ***суффикса -овк/-ёвк***, в ваших примерах его нет вовсе, на другие случаи не распространяется. В остальных же случаях обычно ***О*** под ударением, без ударения - Е, но тоже есть отдельные изъятия, исключения и оговорки. Надо смотреть конкретно.

В отношении слова ***"мелочевка"*** (единственном из всех упомянутых, заслуживающем особого внимания), то здесь ситуация такая. Его написание объясняется тем, что в нем не выделяли суффикс -овк/-ёвк в его основном значении. Дело в том, что семантика суффикса "мелочевки" сильно отличается от той, имеется в "ножовке". По сути дела "мелочевка" - это уменьшительное к "мелочь". Других подобных примеров, вроде, не существует, правил на этот случай нет, поэтому выбор орфографии вполне может диктоваться соображениями удобства, был выбран вариант, отличающий "мелочевку" от "ножовки", но сближающий с отглагольными существительными (от гипотетического глагола "мелочить").

Что качается рекомендаций подведения под общее правило, то они сомнительны и по факту неприятия этих правил за пределами "Грамоты" и по самой идее сведения данного слова к отыменному существительному.

> Из правил Лопатина НА ГРАМОТЕ.РУ

Что Вы называете "правилами Лопатина", если не секрет?
Если ПАС, то при чем тут "Грамота"?

Comment: ПАС действительно не на  "Грамоте", но на "Грамоте" есть Русский орфографический словарь РАН (там мелочовка, плащовка, речовка) и есть Большой толковый словарь русского языка под ред. С. А. Кузнецова, версия 2014 года (там мелочёвка, плащёвка). У Лопатина в ПАС: мелочовка (суфикс ОВК), распашонка (суффикс ОНК),  плащовка (суффикс ОВ+К), трещотка (суффикс ОТК). (У Ефремовой, кстати,  также трещать - трещотка).

Comment: А вопрос в том, почему на Грамоте в словаре Кузнецова пишут до сих пор "мелочёвка, плащёвка", и в том, почему трещотку и распашонку отнесли к исключениям, хотя они считаются отглагольными. Должно же быть какое-то объяснение. Заодно и хорошо бы объяснить колебание в выборе Ё/О в словах  мелочёвка/мелочовка и др.

Comment: @Sibylla,  ПАС и РОС - такие вещи, что они не могут быть "на Грамоте", это вещи самодостаточные, совершенно не важно, где вы их подсмотрели. А ваша формулировка только путает. Типа, на грамоте - одно, а не на грамоте - другое.

Comment: @Sibylla *А вопрос в том, почему на Грамоте в словаре Кузнецова пишут до сих пор "мелочёвка, плащёвка"* - потому, что это пишет Кузнецов, который не собирается бежать с факелом впереди грамотного паровоза. Я объяснял уже много раз, не делаются такие вещи по команде, Лопатин сказал - Кузнецов сделал. Если согласится, введет в следующее издание словаря. Но вряд ли, надо учитывать и личность обоих (в научном плане, разумеется), и общее негативное отношение к новациям Лопатина и Ко. Вопрос надо ставить по-другому. Почему справка выдает за правило то, что по сути является дискуссионным предложением

Comment: А вообще расхождение в словарях - не вопрос. Кузнецов вообще "новатор", но вот тут он просто не мог не быть  консерватором, поскольку его словарь был издан задолго до лопатинских инноваций.

Comment: Но ведь есть толковый словарь под ред. Лопатина, почему Грамота при проверке слов пользуется  орфогр. словарем Лопатина и толковым словарем Кузнецова?

Comment: @Sibylla Понятия не имею, чем пользуется *"Грамота"*. На "Справке" есть сотрудники, которые вольны пользоваться тем, чем считают нужным. И потом есть масса других словарей. На той же "Грамоте" еще пяток выложен. Их авторы тоже должны переучиваться по команде Лопатина? Правописание - вообще то немногое в языке, что задается волей носителей у ученых, но - коллективной волей, проверенной практикой. Чего ж "Справку" толкать на субъекстизм?!

Answer (score 1):

> Как правильно: плащёвка/плащовка, мелочёвка/мелочовка,
>   речёвка/речовка?

На форуме [**ответ**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/193/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) на этот вопрос был дан пять лет назад (узнал о нём **из первой редакции** Вашего, **Sibylla**, вопроса!):

> **Раньше** правильным было написание *мелочёвка, плащёвка:* эти слова считались исключениями. Сейчас их написание подведено под общее
>   правило и зафиксировано в «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН под
>   ред. В. В. Лопатина.

.

Далее. Из Вашего, **Sibylla,** вопроса:

> **Из правил Лопатина НА ГРАМОТЕ.РУ:** Отыменные существительные на ***–овка*** типа **мелочовка, ножовка, плащовка** следует отличать от отглагольных существительных типа *ночёвка.*
>
> А *трещать - **трещотка*** и *распахнуть - **распашонка***, это
>   отглагольные существительные?

Во-первых, на Грамоте.ру нет "правил Лопатина" (как уже было отмечено в этой теме behemothus'ом).

Во-вторых, слова ***трещотка*** и ***распашонка***  оканчиваются не на *-**овк**(а),* а на *-**отк**(а)* и *-**онк**(а)*, и потому можно не обращать внимания на их происхождение.

В этих словах ***о*** пишется в соответствии с след. **[правилом:](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=18#pp18)**

> **§ 18.** После ***ж, ч, ш, щ*** для передачи ударного гласного о пишется буква ***о*** или ***ё.***
>
> Буква ***о*** пишется в следующих случаях.
>
> <...>
>
> 2. В суффиксах имен существительных:
>
> *-**онк**(а)* и *-**онк**(и)*, напр.: *книжонка… **распашонка**...*
>
> *-**отк**(а)*: ***трещотка***.

.

Но если возник попутный вопрос об образовании этих слов…

***Трещотка***. По Тихонову: *трещать - > трещ-отк(а).*

**Распашонка.** По Тихонову: *распахнуть - > распаш-онк(а).*

Но, похоже, не все из лингвистов согласны с отглагольным происхождением *распашонки.* К примеру, вот что говорится у *Бешенковой* и др.  в *"Объяснительном русском орфографическом словаре-справочнике" (М., 2015):*

> Слово образовано от существительного ***распах***, сохранившегося в
>   диалектах, а не от глагола ***распахнуть***.

Comment: slava, я никак не могу получить короткого ответа на вопросы: 1) почему в словаре Кузнецова (ред. 2014 года), который "вывешивает" Грамота.ру,  сохраняется "мелочёвка и плащёвка), путая российских пользователей известного сайта? Они (Лопатин и Кузнецов) что, никак не договорятся? 2) А почему никак не договорятся? Вроде бы решили в отыменных сущ. писать О, а в отглагольных - Ё.  А почему раньше так не писали, что повлияло на это решение? И почему трещотку и распашонку отнесли к исключениям, чем  они не отглагольные? Значит, простое формальное деление не работает.

Comment: Мне кажется, что здесь надо учитывать, что эти суффиксы по природе своей сложные: ОВ/ЁВ+К, ЁН+К или ОНК. И рассматривать надо  именно первую часть. Суффикс ОТ (грохот, топот, цокот) не имеет пары ЕТ, поэтому  трещот - трещотка.  В слове распашонка нет глагольной части суффикса  ЕН/ЁН, поэтому используется суффикс существительного ОНК. Мелочовка подведена под общее правило ОВ/ЕВ +К, хотя и нет прилагательного "мелочевый".

Comment: _**Sibylla: Вроде бы решили в отыменных сущ. писать О, а в отглагольных - Ё.**_  === Кто так решил? Откуда Вы это взяли? В Правилах речь идёт только об отглагольных существительных с суффиксом _**-ёВК**_.  При чём тут _**трещоТКа**_ и _**распашоНКа?**_

Comment: *Но, похоже, не все из лингвистов согласны с отглагольным происхождением распашонки.* - Не в лингвистах дело. Тихонов вообще весьма странный товарищ, когда речь заходит о морфологии. Ну как может трещотка быть от трещать, если "отк" - суффикс не отглагольный? С распашонкой - сложнее, но интересна мотивация  от "распах". Может, и "онк" в конце концов признают суффиксом не отглагольным? Я по крайней мере убедительных примеров, доказывающих его отглагольность не знаю. Печенка? Может быть и от существительного. Варенка? Спорно. **Сгущенка**? Вот, пожалуй, единственное, слова "сгуст", вроде, нету.

Comment: Я думаю: вар/ён/ый - вар/ён/к/а, сгущ/ён/ый - сгущ/ён/к/а, печень - печён/к/а (здесь везде суффикс К).  Кстати Ефремова  в Толковом словаре  словообразовательных частиц не пользуется понятием отглагольный суффикс, у нее: красивый - красотка, трещать - трещотка, один и тот же суффикс ОТК.

Comment: А с "трещоткой" такая ситуация. Я отвечала на вопрос, как правильно и почему пишется трещотка,  не выделяя ее из других слов, а мне прислали комментарий: "Это не лучший ответ, так как трещ..тка - отглагольная форма, значит должно быть ё. Это слово является исключением" Это народ уже ДОМЫСЛИВАЕТ про отглагольные формы, потому что в правилах никаких объяснений нет. И если почитать правила,  мы увидим, что только для выбора О/Ё под ударением даются 7 правил для О и  9 правил для Ё, да еще  авторы меняют эти правила, тоже ничего не объясняя и без полного согласия между собой.