# Плащёвка ― это правильно? Будет ли меняться орфография слова?

Tags: орфография

Из словаря Кузнецова: ПЛАЩЁВКА,  ж. Разг. Плащевая ткань. Синяя п. Юбка из плащёвки.

**Плащ ― плащевой ― плащёвка, груша ― грушевый ― грушовка.** Казалось бы, всё ясно, но народ (на доске объявлений) упрямо пишет ― плащёвка. Смотрю в словарь Кузнецова (**в авторской редакции 2014 года**) ― там тоже "плащёвка".

**Это ― народное решение: только плащёвка, и без вопросов почему.** Так ― больше нравится, так зрительная память уже зафиксировала. Или вот еще причина: потому что  *плащовая ткань, плащовка* ―  это **проф. просторечие**.

**И вопрос:** Нужно считать это слово исключением? Или всё-таки орфографию  изменят (решили изменить, уже изменили)?

Эта проблема уже обсуждался на сайте, но из дискуссии трудно что-либо понять. [Как правильно: плащёвка/плащовка, мелочёвка/мелочовка, речёвка/речовка?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424846/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%91%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0)

На других сайтах: http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?p=265473

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Речовка, мелочовка, плащовка...

Нет глаголов *речевать, мелочевать, плащевать*...

Подробный [ответ Справки](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B2) Грамоты.ру:

> Слово *речовка* **не отглагольное существительное, а отыменное**. К
>   подобной модели в 1950-е годы относилось немного слов, например:
>   *грушовка, ножовка*. Ср.: грушовка – груша и грушевый, ножовка – нож и ножевой, речовка – речь и речевой. Орфография таких существительных
>   полностью соответствует правилам. К тому же написания грушовка,
>   ножовка были закреплены в «Толковом словаре русского языка» под ред.
>   Д. Н. Ушакова.
>
> Во второй половине ХХ в. появляются еще два существительных на -[о]вка
>   после шипящего: ***мелочёвка*** и ***плащёвка*** (оба впервые
>   зафиксированы в словаре «Новые слова и значения» с буквой *ё*: первое
>   – в издании 1984 г. второе – в издании 1997 г.). Эти орфографические
>   варианты отражали практику письма. Вероятно, на написание этих слов с
>   *ё (е)* повлиял основной принцип русской графики – обозначать гласными буквами твердость и мягкость предшествующих согласных (ср.: мял – мал,
>   люк – лук, мёл – мол). Написания *грушовка, ножовка*, устаревшее
>   *размежовка* также соответствуют этому принципу: в них *о* писали после твердых согласных, в словах *плащевка, мелочевка, речевка* стали
>   писать *е* после мягких. Наличие правила о суффиксах отыменных
>   существительных оказалось менее значимым фактором.
>
> Распространенное написание с буквой *ё (е)* в новообразованиях
>   *плащёвка, мелочёвка* было утверждено в качестве нормативного «Орфографическим словарем русского языка» 1991 г. Однако при
>   подготовке новой редакции «Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации»
>   2006 г., когда учеными было рассмотрено все многообразие слов, в том
>   числе новых, с проблемой *о* и *ё* после шипящих, орфографическую
>   рекомендацию было решено пересмотреть, чтобы подвести слова
>   ***мелочовка, плащовка, речовка*** под общее правило, не закреплять новые исключения (ср. с уже устоявшимися *грушовка, ножовка*).

Comment: Интересно, что у Кузнецова: плащёвка, речовка, мелочовка, то есть плащёвка на особом положении.  Речь - речовка, мелочь - мелочовка, здесь скорее суффикс сущ. ОВК (нет слова "мелочЁвый", а "речевой"  плохо соотносится с "речёвкой"). Поэтому плащёвка  - это нечто особенное, может быть, стоит оставить ее в исключениях, чтобы отмежеваться от проф. "плащовый/плащовка".

Comment: Никаких оснований - именно потому, что не существует глагола *плащевать*. Ср.: *ночёвка - ночевать*. У Кузнецова вообще тьма-тьмуща ошибок. ***Она умна, мила, наконец хорошо воспитанна.***  http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&all=x

Comment: Не бывает правил без исключений, как бы нам этого ни хотелось, собственный характер слова, его  историю приходится иногда учитывать. Вот почему мы пишем учебник - учёба, здесь чередование не в корне, и суффикс существительного, а не глагола, хотя слово и мотивировано глаголом. Учёба - это исключение, его запоминают.

Comment: @Galina Avanesova У меня стойкое ощущение, что слова эти образуются _от прилагательных_ через их суффиксы ев/ёв, а не от существительных или глаголов. В этом смысле, с плащёвкой всё в порядке (плащевая ткань), речёвка (этакая _речевая_ форма) в написании "речовка" для меня выглядит просто дико, "мелочовка" - странно (я попытался понять, почему, и нашёл в нескольких книгах "мелочёвый"). Ножовка - либо исключение, либо по происхождению не было "ножевой пилой".

Comment: Грушовка же (не знаю, что это), видимо, происходит от диалектно-просторечного "грушовый" (по созвучию с "грошовым" - нет прилагательного "грошевОй") вместо нормального "грушевая (настойка?)" (грушёвка). Таким образом, малоакадемические циркулярщики без реальных оснований подогнали всё под  самобытную "ножовку", так и не достигнув желанной цели всё обобщить к чертям собачьим.